The editor crashes as soon as I enter play mode
I've coded a road generator in Unity. It was working fine, but recently I must have changed something, because always when I want to enter play mode, the Unity Editor crashes. As you can see, I use Instantiate method pretty much.
Here's the generator class (not full, I pasted here only the necessary methods):
public class Generator : MonoBehaviour, IDisposable
{
    // Here are variables definitions

    private void Awake()
    {
        world = GameObject.Find("World").transform;
        manager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
        carBehaviour = GameObject.Find("PlayerCar").GetComponent<CarBehaviour>();
        manager.level.SetGenerator(this);

        ReBuild += GenerateLevel;
        manager.DestroyMessage += OnLevelDestroy;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            GenerateLevel(50, 7);
        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Failed to generate new level. Loading first level from the list of saved levels.");
            manager.LoadLevel(1);
        }
    }

    public void GenerateLevel(int length, int chanceOfTurn) => GenerateLevel(length, chanceOfTurn, (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    public void GenerateLevel(int length, int chanceOfTurn, int seed)
    {
        if (!enabled)
            throw new Exception("Unable to generate level because generator is not enabled.");

        drivenDistance = 0;
        random = new Rand(seed);
        map = new bool[GameManager.WORLD_SIZE, GameManager.WORLD_SIZE];

        Vector3 startPosition = carBehaviour.transform.position;
        startPosition.y -= 20f;
        transform.SetPositionAndRotation(startPosition, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (!enabled)
                throw new OperationCanceledException();

            try
            {
                GenerateRoad(1, transform.rotation, random, ramps);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.LogException(exception);
                ReBuild(length, chanceOfTurn);
            }
            
            if (random.Next(0, chanceOfTurn) == 0)
                CreateTurn(random.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? 'r' : 'l');

            if (random.Next(0, 10) == 0 && breaks)
                CreateBreak(transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }

        CreateFinish(transform.position, transform.rotation);
        OnLevelBuilt();
        Dispose();
    }

    private void GenerateRoad(int length, Quaternion rotation, Rand random, bool withRamps)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (withRamps && drivenDistance > 30)
                if (random.Next(0, 10) == 0)
                    CreateRamp(transform.position + rampOffset, rotation);

            int x = (int)Math.Round(transform.position.x / 10 / SIZE) + GameManager.WORLD_SIZE / 2;
            int y = (int)Math.Round(transform.position.z / 10 / SIZE) + GameManager.WORLD_SIZE / 2;

            try
            {
                if (map[x, y])
                    manager.ResetLevel();
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) 
            {
                Debug.LogWarning($"There is no element with index [{x}, {y}] on the map array. The maximum size of the array is [{GameManager.WORLD_SIZE}, {GameManager.WORLD_SIZE}]");
            }

            CreateRoadPart(roadPrefab, rotation);
 
            transform.position += 10 * SIZE * transform.forward;
            drivenDistance += 10 * SIZE;
        }
    }

    private void CreateTurn(char direction)
    {
        if (direction == 'r')
        {
            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
            CreateRoadPart(roadTurnPrefab, transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0));
            transform.position += 10 * SIZE * transform.forward;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0);
            CreateRoadPart(roadTurnPrefab, transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0));
            transform.position += 10 * SIZE * transform.forward;
        }
    }

    private GameObject CreateRoadPart(GameObject prefab, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        GameObject road = Instantiate(prefab, transform.position, rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0));
        road.transform.localScale = new Vector3(SIZE, SIZE, SIZE);
        road.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;
        road.transform.SetParent(world);

        if (road == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Road is null", road);
            return null;
        }

        if (prefab == roadPrefab)
            manager.level.road.Add(road);
        else if (prefab == roadTurnPrefab)
            manager.level.turns.Add(road);

        int x = (int)Math.Round(transform.position.x / 10 / SIZE) + GameManager.WORLD_SIZE / 2;
        int y = (int)Math.Round(transform.position.z / 10 / SIZE) + GameManager.WORLD_SIZE / 2;

        try
        {
            map[x, y] = true;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning($"There is no element with index [{x}, {y}] on the map array. The maximum size of the array is [{GameManager.WORLD_SIZE}, {GameManager.WORLD_SIZE}]");
        }
        return road;
    }
}

I have already tried to use Task.Delay(5) after each call of Instantiate, but it didn't work. I have also tried to open an another thread but it also didn't work.
I expect the code to stop crashing.

Assuming you mean crashing, is the code producing an exception?  What specifically is failing?  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation produces the exception?

usually crashing implies some form of infinite loop

Sorry, maybe I used wrong word. I mean the unity editor stops working, the window is still open, but I can't do anything in it.

@2215436235523676312513513: Perhaps you have some infinite loop or other resource constraint?  Now is the time to start digging into your debugging to narrow down the problem.  Test without recent changes, include debugging output in the code (writing logs to a file for example), use a step debugger, etc.  Your goal is to narrow down the specific code where the problem is happening.

If your GenerateRoad throws, the exception is handled in GenerateLevel where you trigger a ReBuild, which calls GenerateLevel again. As nothing has changed in the data, it can't rebuild, so it throws again and tries to rebuild again etc. This is an infinite recursion (it can only end with stack overflow exception).
Try commenting out that ReBuild invocation and see if the Editor still freezes. This may not be the only problem in your code, but at least this is the one that's clearly visible.

I've tried this but it didn't help. I had made a log and I noticed the editor freezes even if the catch block is never called. According to the log, it finishes the GenerateLevel method.

In this case, you can only try to comment out manager.LoadLevel(1); in Start because this is the only thing that can execute outside your GenerateMethod. If this doesn't help, then the problem is outside the code you provided.
